# Не работает функция backgroundImage, c backgroundColor проблем нет

Tags: javascript

```
function change(ob) {
  var tbs = document.getElementsByTagName('td');
  for (var i = 0; i < tbs.length; i++) {
    if (i == ob.cells.value - 1) {
      change_color(ob, tbs, i);
      change_background(ob, tbs, i);
    }
  }
}

function change_color(ob, tbs, i) {
  switch (ob.color.value) {
    case 'w': {
      tbs[i].style.backgroundColor = '#FFFFFF';
      break;
    }
    case 'r': {
      tbs[i].style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
      break;
    }
    case 'y': {
      tbs[i].style.backgroundColor = '#FFFF00';
      break;
    }
    case 'g': {
      tbs[i].style.backgroundColor = '#008000';
      break;
    }
    case 'b': {
      tbs[i].style.backgroundColor = '#0000FF';
      break;
    }
  }
}

function change_background(ob, tbs, i) {
  switch (ob.pic.value) {
    case '0': {
      tbs[i].style.backgroundImage = '';
      break;
    }
    case 'j': {
      tbs[i].style.backgroundImage = 'java.png';
      break;
    }
    case 'js': {
      tbs[i].style.backgroundImage = 'js.png';
      break;
    }
    case 'c': {
      tbs[i].style.backgroundImage = 'c.png';
      break;
    }
    case 'p': {
      tbs[i].style.backgroundImage = 'python.png';
      break;
    }
  }
}
`введите сюда код`;
```

Comment: Все картинки в той же папке, что и файл html

Comment: кажется, надо писать  .backgroundImage = 'url(путь_картинки)'

Comment: Эх, спасибо большое))0)